# Upgrading DLL's - Nuget Packages in Legacy Application

Tags: c#, .net, dll, nuget

I'm having a task to upgrade DLL's in a Legacy Application I'm planning to do it via Nuget Package Manager, but I'm having couple of questions here:

1. Consider ProjectB has reference to `System.ValueTuple, Version 1.0`.

- Now whenever I try to upgrade to `System.ValueTuple, Version 2.0` via NuGet package manager it creates a entry for `RestSharp` in the project's app.config file with attributes like `dependentAssembly,bindingRedirection` for `Restsharp` which is totally unrelated to `System.ValueTuple`.

  - Why it this happening?

2. Since I got some new entries in `app.config` file for ProjectB. So do I need to add those entries manully in other Projects (e.g.: `ProjectA`, `ProjectE`) `app.config` files where `ProjectB.dll` is referenced?

Comment: What version of .NET Framework is your legacy application targeting? You shouldn't need to reference `System.ValueTuple.dll` anymore.

Comment: Also, are you using `<PackageReference>` - or are you using `packages.config`? Are you able to upgrade your `.csproj` MSBuild files to the new "minimal" aka "SDK-style"? Most project-types (except WebForms...) can be upgraded.

Comment: System.ValueTuple is just given for an example. And I'm using packages.config

Comment: I suggest you migrate away from `packages.config` then, as the VS wizard will remove unnecessary references too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference